# Loosing fps, javascript game

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i am using p5.js framework to building games for mobiles.
Recently i developed simple pong game and i have some isue with fps.
My problem is that its pretty hard to get 60 fps on my devices, only xiaomi mi5 can handle it without laggs.

My part of code in draw function(60 fps) look like this:

```js
 background(bR, bG, bB); 
 fill(R,G,B);
 noStroke();
 rect(0, 0, width, height/35);
 rect(width - width/25, 0, width/25, height);
  
 rect(0, height - height/8, width, height/8);  
 for(var i = 0; i<width; i+=width/13)
 triangle(i, height-height/8, i+width/13, height-height/8, i+width/13/2, (height-height/8)*0.97); 
  
  
 rect(0, 0, width/25, height); 
   
 rect(0, height - height/4.2, width*0.08, height/150); 
 rect(width*0.15, height - height/4.2, width, height/150); 
 fill(255);
 ellipse(width*0.5, height*0.44, width*0.5, width*0.5); 
 
 showPlayer();
 updatePlayer();
 
 fill(bR, bG, bB);
 textSize(width/3);
 textFont(font);
 textAlign(CENTER);
 text(showScore(), width/2, height/2);
```

Maybe the problem is that i am using too much percentage value?

Comment: My advice would be to check the devices you're testing on can actually handle 60FPS in terms of refresh rate, as I can imagine most mobile devices won't.

Comment: They are able to do that, other games like that running smoothly.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can actually run, preferably in something like a CodePen or JSFiddle.

Comment: Show us showPlayer() and updatePlayer(), they are probably the most power-eating parts